# How to create a curved plastic material as a spray can lid

Tags: modeling

I'm a beginning blender user and I'm trying to dabble in 3D modeling. I might be biting off more than I can chew but I am attempting to create a 3D model of the following object: [image: Shipped cream tube]

I currently have a few cylinders matching the dimensions of the object (I used set background and one of those numpad views to get the proportions right). My next step is to create the top lid part.

[image: Cylinders]

My main question is: Which blender tools can I use to round off the top and create creases that swirl?

Answer (score 4):

This should be pretty simple.
All you need is the *Subdivision modifier* (3 levels work great)

1. Create the base "flower shape" by scaling vertices
2. Fill and extrude into a cylinder (add some loopcuts)
3. Scale and rotate the top

<sup>You can of course polish it some more, i just kept this answer brief.</sup>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approximation:

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, select Mesh > UV Sphere. In the Add UV Sphere properies box set the number of Segments to (for instance) 33. Go into Edit mode and delete the bottom half of the sphere. Then press numpad <kbd>7</kbd> to go into topview and select every 3rd edge loop that goes form the outside to the center.
(Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> with some precision clicking to select multiple edge loops at once)

[image]

In object mode press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and choose Cursor to Selected. Set the Transform Pivot Point to 3D Cursor.

[image]

In Edit mode press <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>.</kbd> then <kbd>9</kbd>, then hit enter to confirm the 90% scaling.

[image]

Now press numpad <kbd>1</kbd> to go into sideview and select all bottom vertices.

[image]

Now press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the bottom a little. Then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to repeat it a couple of times.

[image]

Now add a Simple Deform modifier to the object and set the modifier to Twist and set it to the Z axis. Then smooth shade to object to make it look smooth.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So I started with a cylinder, modeled into the overall shape of the lid, then inset some of the faces to give me the basic form of the "divot".

[image]

Spend as much time as you can with low-geo so that its easier to make big shape adjustments, then when you have the big parts down,add a subsurf mod and apply it so that  can have a bit more geometry to work with.

Then select the part you just modeled, invert everything except that part and delete it.

[image]

Then add a [radial array](https://youtu.be/0fiJVTmw5Wc) modifier and then "rebuild" your old shape, that way you can symmetrize it around the object easily.

[image]

Add a vertex group and add the top half of the vertices to that group.

[image]

You might consider going to Weight paint mode and using a gradient to add the verts there, so it "smooths" the effect out a bit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNFY8.png)

Then I add a Simple Deform modifier > Twist and use an empty object to control the origin. Set it to only affect the vertex group. Fiddle with the degrees and Limits if need be.

[image]

Then I add another subsurf just to smooth it out.

Result:

[image]